# MongoDB - "The dollar ($) prefixed field \'$$hashKey\' in \'fieldName".$$hashKey\' is not valid for storage.'"

Tags: mongodb

While trying to update a document I'm getting the above error for the field `timesToDisplay`.

MongoDB version 2.6.7.

The whole model:

```
msg = {
          'name': '',
          'template': '',
          'displayDurInMilliSec': 0,
          'timesToDisplay': [],
          'images': [],
          'texts': [],
          'screen': []
       }
```

I guess I will be getting the same error with the other 3 array fields.

I've tried using `$set` but sill getting the same error.

The code:

```
function updateMessage(msg) {
    var conditions = {_id: msg._id}
      , update = { 'name': msg.name,
                   'template': msg.template,
                   'displayDurInMilliSec': msg.displayDurInMilliSec,
                   'timesToDisplay': msg.timesToDisplay,
                   'images': msg.images,
                   'texts': msg.texts,
                   'screen': msg.screen
    }

    messageModel.update(conditions, update, callback);

    function callback(err, numAffected) {
        if (!err) console.log(numAffected)
        else console.log(err)
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** The `msg` parameter is a document in itself:

```
{ _id: '557d58abd54955480db6694f',
  name: 'msg99',
  timesToDisplay: [ { startDate: '2015-06-19T21:00:00.000Z',
                   '$$hashKey': 'object:214',
                    endDate: '2015-06-25T21:00:00.000Z',
                    daysOfTheWeek: [Object],
                    startTimeOfDay: '11',
                    endTimeOfDay: '13' } ],
 images: [],
 texts: [],
 screen: [ 1 ],
 '$$hashKey': 'object:54',
 displayDurInMilliSec: '40189',
 template: 'templates/Template2.html' }
```

Comment: Well it's a pretty simple message. Unfortunately you are not showing us what you are containing in your own `msg` variable. That is no doubt the problem here. Plus **really bad way to do this**. You should be using **`$set`** and **`$push`** and other operators that do not just "replace" the entire document on update.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've edited the question. I guess I will need to remove the `$$hashKey` fields.

Comment: Well you do need to do that. Anything "prefixed" with `$` is considered "reserved". MongoDB uses these fore "operators" in various areas. Therefore it is illegal to try and name a field in storage with a `$` prefix. Clear enough? The message really should have that full text.

Answer (score 6):

The `$$hashkey` field is added by AngularJS when working with ngRepeat or ngOptions. In the case of ngRepeat you can change the repeat string by appending `track by $index` to it. For using ngOptions you'll have to filter out that field yourself. AngularJS provides a quick solution for filtering it out: `angular.toJson`. This will filter out all fields prefixed with two dollar signs. [Check out the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson).

I realize that this isn't a MongoDB answer, but this specific error ($$hashkey), is usually due to AngularJS.